# detected an exception: Unexpected database connector error

Tags: crystal-reports

Am doing Java EE application with crystal reports. I have different datasources to logon. my reports are working fine when am connecting particular datasource which I was connected at the design time but while switching to other datasource getting the following error.

```
"http-bio-8080"-exec-5 JRCCommunicationAdapter ERROR -  detected an exception: Unexpected database connector error
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.datafoundation.DFQuery.for(SourceFile:632)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.datalayer.a.do(SourceFile:1621)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.datalayer.a.a(SourceFile:1404)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.m.b(SourceFile:334)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.j.b(SourceFile:515)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.m.o(SourceFile:408)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.m.a(SourceFile:173)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.ContextNode.a(SourceFile:114)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.ContextNode.a(SourceFile:95)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.j.case(SourceFile:1080)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.h.<init>(SourceFile:108)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataContext.a(SourceFile:254)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.a(SourceFile:4660)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.a(SourceFile:4574)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.new(SourceFile:2652)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.byte(SourceFile:2610)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.try(SourceFile:2282)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.int(SourceFile:2442)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.dataengine.DataProcessor2.I(SourceFile:1013)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.objectformatter.ObjectFormatter.fo(SourceFile:526)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.paginator.PageFormatter.if(SourceFile:613)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.paginator.PageFormatter.a(SourceFile:578)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.paginator.PageFormatter.X(SourceFile:387)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.formatter.formatter.paginator.PageFormatter.moveToPageN(SourceFile:339)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportViewingRequestHandler.a(SourceFile:1090)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.requesthandler.ReportViewingRequestHandler.byte(SourceFile:218)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.do(SourceFile:1909)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.if(SourceFile:661)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.a(SourceFile:167)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.a(SourceFile:529)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter$2.call(SourceFile:527)
    at com.crystaldecisions.reports.common.ThreadGuard.syncExecute(SourceFile:102)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.for(SourceFile:525)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.int(SourceFile:424)
    at com.businessobjects.reports.sdk.JRCCommunicationAdapter.request(SourceFile:352)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.a.a(SourceFile:54)
    at com.businessobjects.sdk.erom.jrc.a.execute(SourceFile:67)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent$a.execute(SourceFile:716)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.CommunicationChannel.a(SourceFile:125)
    at com.crystaldecisions.proxy.remoteagent.RemoteAgent.a(SourceFile:537)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ds.a(SourceFile:186)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportSource.a(SourceFile:1558)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.ReportSource.getPage(SourceFile:767)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.report.application.AdvancedReportSource.getPage(SourceFile:324)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.event.s.a(SourceFile:158)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.event.s.a(SourceFile:127)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.event.bt.a(SourceFile:47)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.a.e.a(SourceFile:396)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.a.t.a(SourceFile:1726)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.event.bw.broadcast(SourceFile:97)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.event.am.a(SourceFile:53)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.a.t.if(SourceFile:2104)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.e.a(SourceFile:300)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.e.a(SourceFile:202)
    at com.businessobjects.report.web.e.a(SourceFile:135)
    at com.crystaldecisions.report.web.ServerControl.a(SourceFile:607)
    at com.crystaldecisions.report.web.ServerControl.processHttpRequest(SourceFile:342)
    at org.apache.jsp.jsp.FPIPPlanDetails_jsp._jspService(FPIPPlanDetails_jsp.java:183)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:419)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:112)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I know this question is nearly 7 years old, but this comment is mostly made for people stumbling on this question now. I had this issue, and the problem was that I was giving the wrong driver to the report. SAP also reccomends that you ensure the correct driver is in the project's classpath. If you're encountering this issue, be sure to check all o your connection info such as the hostname, databasename, user and password.

Answer (score 0):

My own experience with this has been that if the object is in any way not a List where the object is a properly formatted java bean, you get this. Hope it points you in the right direction.